# Custom Filters/Validators in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework application structure as below:

```
/application
/library
    /Zend
    /Core
        /Filter
            /MyFilter.php
        /Validator
            /MyValidator.php
```

I would like to put custom filters and validators in their respective folders and have them loaded automatically when used. However, I cannot figure out how to best accomplish this.

I need the solution to work with Zend_Filter_Input in this fashion:

```
$filters = array(
    'month'   => 'Digits',
    'account' => 'StringTrim',
    'other'   => 'MyFilter'
);

$validators = array(
    'account' => 'Alpha',
    'other'   => 'MyValidator'
);

$inputFilter = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
```

What I already know:

- Core_Filter_MyFilter implements Zend_Filter_Interface
- Obviously, the filters and validators are already in my include path.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I designed and implemented `Zend_Filter_Input` back in 2007.

You can add new class prefixes to help load your custom filter and validator classes.  By default, `Zend_Filter_Input` searches for classes that have the prefixes `"Zend_Filter"` and `"Zend_Validate"`.  Try this:

```
$inputFilter->addNamespace('Core_Filter');
```

Before you run `isValid()` or other methods of the object.

Alternatively, you can also pass a new class prefix string in the options array, the fourth argument to the `Zend_Filter_Input` constructor:

```
$options = array('inputNamespace' => 'Core_Filter');
$inputFilter = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data, $options);
```

See also the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.input.html#zend.filter.input.namespaces) I wrote for `Zend_Filter_Input`.

Comment: Excellent! I spent hours reading through the documentation but I must have missed this being mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: So this is what SO defines as being 'the definitive answer on a given question' :)

Comment: @BillKarwin, The documentation link is broken. Can you provide an update one ?

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin, I have fixed the link.